# Openmeetings screenshare, share particular window

Tags: red5, screensharing, openmeetings, desktop-sharing

I am using openmeetings.
Everything is working fine. But, I need some changes in screenshare and screenrecording features. Here are my requirements.
I need to record videos irrespective of sharing screen. I have two scenarios:
**1) When screenshare is not enabled**
In openmeetings screenrecord is recording the entire screen. I need to record only whiteboard part in openmeetings. Even when I minimize or open other window, it should record only whiteboard part.

**2) When screenshare is enabled**
All other windows (except openmeetings moderator window) which are active should be recorded.  But when the moderator window is active I need to record only whiteboard part. So, need to skip chat and settings tabs.So, If its not openmeetings window, record entire screen, if it is openmeetings window (browser) record only whiteboard.